# C4201 warning in C code

Tags: c++, c

Will this warning create any problem in runtime?

ext.h(180) : warning C4201: nonstandard extension used : nameless struct/union

Comment: Check this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c89bw853.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is when you have a union or struct without a name, e.g.:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    }; // no name
    int c;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct m;
m.a = 4;
m.b = 6; //overwrites m.a
m.c = 8;
```

It allows you to access members of the union as if they were members of the struct. When you give the union a name (which is what the standard requires), you must access `a` and `b` through the name of the union instead:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    } u;
    int c;
}

MyStruct m;
m.u.a = 4;
m.u.b = 6; // overwrites m.u.a
m.c = 8;
```

It is not an issue as long as you compile your code using compilers that share this extension, it is only a problem when you compile your code using compilers that *don't*, and because the standard doesn't require this behaviour, a compiler is free to reject this code.

**Edit:** As pointed out by andyn, C11 explicitly allows this behaviour.

Comment: That's actually valid in C11.

Comment: @andyn: Indeed, I forgot about that. C11 still doesn't have the support I'd like it to. Pelles is about the only compiler I know of that's bothered with C11. Clang and GCC are adding bits here and there. I don't even know the status of any of the commercial ones.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a MSVC warning, which tells you that you are using an compiler specific language extension. so you can **[check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c89bw853%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

> **nonstandard extension used : nameless struct/union**
>
> Under Microsoft extensions (/Ze), you can specify a structure without a declarator as members of another structure or union. These structures generate an error under ANSI compatibility (/Za).

```
// C4201.cpp
// compile with: /W4
struct S
{
   float y;
   struct
   {
      int a, b, c;  // C4201
   };
} *p_s;

int main()
{
}
```

If you are not bothered about portability of your code. i.e: Your target platform is only MSVC then simply ignore the warning.

Comment: What's odd is that this warning still pops up even when compiling with the MSVC `-std:c11` compiler flag.

Comment: @jdk1.0 I just had the same problem. The warning is still shown in C11 mode (-std:c11). I have to explicitely suppress that specific warning. It works with other compilers in C11 mode, though. I can't seem to find much information about this MSVC bug (?). Since anonymous structs/unions have been supported for a long time in MSVC as an extension, I would have thought it would be easy to enable it in C11 mode. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not create any problem, it just means that your code is not standards compliant, which means that it might not compile with some other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is compiler supported it *should* work ok until you decide to port to a new platform (or use a new compiler), or they withdraw support.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the same problem as [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845911/how-can-i-prevent-a-nameless-struct-union)

Just give a name to your structs / unions

E.g.

```
struct mystruct {
   ...
}
```